# При использовании регулярных выражений НЕ работает замена, а точнее перестановка переменных в Javascript/

Tags: javascript, регулярные-выражения, замена

```
function bbtagit(text) {

    text = text.replace(/^[<ZAP><N_ZAP>]([\d\D\w\W\s\S]*)[<\/N_ZAP>]([\d\D\w\W\s\S]*)[<LITE>]([\d\D\w\W\s\S]*)[<\/LITE><\/ZAP>]$/gim, '<ZAP><N_ZAP>$3<\/N_ZAP><UMU>$1<\/UMU\><\/ZAP>');


    return text;

}

var line = "<ZAP><N_ZAP>65555</N_ZAP><UMU>dsf</UMU><LITE>523</LITE></ZAP>";


console.log(bbtagit(line)); //выдает <ZAP><N_ZAP></N_ZAP><UMU>ZAP><N_ZAP>65555</N_ZAP><UMU>dsf</UMU><LITE>523</LITE</UMU></ZAP>
```

Данная функция выдает

```
<ZAP><N_ZAP></N_ZAP><UMU>ZAP><N_ZAP>65555</N_ZAP><UMU>dsf</UMU><LITE>523</LITE</UMU></ZAP>
```

Как добиться вида

```
<ZAP><N_ZAP>523<\/N_ZAP><UMU>65555<\/UMU\><\/ZAP>
```

Что я делаю не так??? Не могу понять что в регулярке не так?

Answer (score 0):

```
function bbtagit(text) {

    text = text.replace(/^<ZAP><N_ZAP>([\d\D\w\W\s\S]*)<\/N_ZAP>([\d\D\w\W\s\S]*)<LITE>([\d\D\w\W\s\S]*)<\/LITE><\/ZAP>$/gim, '<ZAP><N_ZAP>$3<\/N_ZAP><UMU>$1<\/UMU\><\/ZAP>');


    return text;

}

var line = "<ZAP><N_ZAP>65555</N_ZAP><UMU>dsf</UMU><LITE>523</LITE></ZAP>";


alert(bbtagit(line));
```

Проблема крылась в квадратных скобках [], после того как их убрал, переменные начали определяться правильно